# How to select using Left Function with a condition in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, conditional-statements

In postgres I could use the following:

```
SELECT LEFT([COLUMN], 1) = 'B'
FROM [DB].[dbo].[TABLE]
```

But in SQL Server doesn't work the use of "="

How can make this works it out in SQL Server.

Comment: `case when LEFT([COLUMN], 1) = 'B' then true else false end`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name still a get as a wrong syntaxis around of "="

Comment: There must be something else, because the comparison works (you just need to put `true` and `false` in single quotes because SQL Server does not support booleans) see here: http://rextester.com/ORDT88528

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP asked about a postgresql syntax which is really odd in the eyes of sql server. I guess you want to return a column of boolean values?
Then the problem would be that sql server does not have a boolean datatype altogether! But you can use BIT and assign meaning to 0, 1 and NULL. It is not built-in however.

As for the headline "How to select using Left Function with a condition in SQL Server?", it is dead simple: CASE-END statement supports LEFT function. There is one caveat, however, which is the two different syntaxes of CASE-END:

Syntax 1:

```
CASE [Column] WHEN 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Syntax 2:

```
CASE WHEN [Column] = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

The **big** difference between the two is: Syntax 1 make all conditions check against the same value (i.e. [Column]), whereas syntax 2 support differing condition clauses. And they can't be mixed. For example:
1)

```
CASE LEFT([Column],1) WHEN 'B' THEN 1 WHEN LEFT([Column],2) = 'Ca' THEN 2 ELSE 0 END
```

throw a syntax error on the "=", while 2)

```
CASE WHEN LEFT([Column],1) = 'B' THEN 1 WHEN LEFT([Column],2) = 'Ca' THEN 2 ELSE 0 END
```

works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing wrong with `LEFT` function but to return `true` or `false` after evaluating the *expression* you need `CASE` or `IIF` statement in `SQL server`

```
case when LEFT([COLUMN], 1) = 'B' then 'true' else 'false' end
```

or

```
IIF(LEFT([COLUMN], 1) = 'B','true','false' )
```